# Como posso passar String.concat "/" [""; "usr"; "local"; "bin"] para c?

Tags: c

Sei muitas coisas em c, porém, isso é novo para mim, mas, veja abaixo com OCaml: Gerando um nome de arquivo de componentes: Observe que o segundo argumento é uma lista de strings.

> - String.concat "/" [""; "usr"; "local"; "bin"]

É bem simples e fácil de ser utilizado.  Isso gera como output ....

> - : string = "/usr/local/bin"

Como posso passar tranformar isso para c? Queria entender como fazer isso em c!

Queria usar isso com: document.write() com um printf.

Passos:

O programa insere:

> - String.concat "/" [""; "usr"; "local"; "bin"]

Gera:

> - : string = "/usr/local/bin"

E então dá um:

> - document.write()

E depois transforma:

> - document.write("/usr/local/bin");

E então em:

> - printf.

O que quero com isso?

> - Quero criar um diretório! E assim inserir arquivos ou dados nesse diretório!

Porque document.write(); ?

> - É que eu quero inserir esse diretório no documento e referenciar - lo.

Porque printf?

> - Porque o printf faz um document.write() de verdade, escrevendo em arquivo dados.

Comment: Poderia ser em C++?

Comment: Pode ser feita sim em c++. Isso ajudaria bastante! Você conseguiria fazer, se sim: - mostre - me, POR FAVOR.

Comment: Não poste comentários como se fossem respostas.

Answer (score 0):

Esta é uma solução sem muitas validações:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
using namespace std;


class String
{
public:
    string concat ( const string val)
    {
        vector _tokens;
        string delimiters(" \"\';[]"); 

        Tokenize ( string(val), _tokens, delimiters);
        vector::iterator iv = _tokens.begin();

        for(int i=2; i < _tokens.size(); i++)
        {
            _tokens[i] = _tokens[0] + _tokens[i];
        }

        return accumulate(_tokens.begin(), _tokens.end(), string(""));;
    }

private:
    void Tokenize(const string & str,
                  vector & tokens,
                  const string & delimiters = " ")
    {
        // Skip delimiters at beginning.
        string::size_type lastPos = str.find_first_not_of(delimiters, 0);
        // Find first "non-delimiter".
        string::size_type pos     = str.find_first_of(delimiters, lastPos);

        while (string::npos != pos || string::npos != lastPos)
        {
            // Found a token, add it to the vector.
            tokens.push_back(str.substr(lastPos, pos - lastPos));
            // Skip delimiters.  Note the "not_of"
            lastPos = str.find_first_not_of(delimiters, pos);
            // Find next "non-delimiter"
            pos = str.find_first_of(delimiters, lastPos);
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    String MyString;

    string path = MyString.concat("\"/\" [\"\"; \"usr\"; \"local\"; \"bin\"]" );

    return 0;
}
```